# [Node][Mongo] Trying to add data to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backend

i have problem.

I have MERN (Mongo, Express, React, Node) and trying save data to database from simple form.

Currently i having MongoDB, Robo 3T for management data

Sucessfully i sending data from React to Node Backend.

I have problem with connect Node Backend and save data to MongoDB.

Data is sending by json.

Here is my endpoint:

```
app.post('/receive', (req, res) => {

  console.log(req.body);

});
```

After this i can get in console:

In Front:
[image]

In Back:

[image]

Finally, what should i write to save this data to MongoDB from node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/

```
app.post('/receive', (req, res) => {

    <db>.<collection>.insert( { name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email } )

});
```

however in this case youll need to have defined mongo with a db and a collection. Your above code isnt showing you how you hooked up mongo so I can't provide that unfortunately.

Comment: So i need create Collection & Schema, and after it can i upload to database?

Comment: Assuming you have a local db already setup, then yes you'll need to access that via JavaScript code, I typically use mongoose to do this though you could use plain mongo.

Comment: here's an example of using mongoose to hook it up. https://github.com/mcpengelly/passport-local-session-auth/blob/master/server.js#L6 I dont do inserts for this though. for that you'll need to reference my answer above

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BTqsXjzs

Here is my code. I connect to Mongo correct.

Now i need create a schema and collection in node files?

Comment: ReferenceError: db is not defined

Comment: that should work but you need to move the res.json() to the bottom of the express route. res.json() sends a response back and once that is done no other actions are completed.

Comment: sorry you need to do. TestSchema.insert({ /* the data */}) and also what i mentioned above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172620/discussion-between-matt-pengelly-and-piotr-zak).

Comment: Hmm, now displaying

 TypeError: TestSchema.insert is not a function

In Backend console.

Comment: i started a chat for this. can you check that out?

Comment: `TestSchema.create({name: req.body.name})` Please check out the chat i started so we can continue this outside of comments

Comment: This is because you are not getting a reference to db. Replace mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/27017'); with db =mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/27017');. I hope this helps you.